# How to remember user using jwt even after browser closes?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to implement json web token for my user authentication using jsonwebtoken and express-jwt in my expressjs, nodejs and angularjs app. I read various articles and tutorials and now I am a little confused about something.

First of what I understood about JWT is it is composed of three parts separated by period:

1. Header: Describes the jwt and the algorithm.
2. Payload: Contains the information:issuer, audience, expiry
3. Signature: signature based on header and payload

So every request is made with the token, which is validated at server. According to [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-json-web-tokens-node-js/) article, issuer is the one who makes request. In case of user authentication, user is the issuer. Now using [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) middleware, validated the token in request header and attaches the decoded token to req.user:

```
app.use(expressJwt({ secret: jwtSecret }).unless({ path: [ '/login' ]}));
```

How long can be the length of payload? And how and where do I save token on client side so my session persists even after browser closes, unless the user logs out, like facebook's "keep logged in"? Because I dont want the user to be prompted to log in again if the token expires, I want the token to renew unless the user logs out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may store JWT in a persistent cookie or [browser local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). The length of the payload is not limited by the JWT itself but by the storage. Remember that long tokens may add significant load to your requests or might need extra server configuration to allow extra long HTTP headers.

If you do not want JWT tokens to expire, set the expiration time accordingly when issuing them. This is an additional security risk if JWT leaks as user has no way to revoke them.

Comment: I want the JWT to be persistent. Because I dont want to prompt user for signin unless he logs out of the system. Does the jwt be destroyed after the browser is closed if we store it in localStorage?

Comment: As described on the w3schools page: HTML local storage provides two objects for storing data on the client: (1) window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date and (2) window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the tab is closed). So - yes, localStorage will not be lost when browser window is closed.

Comment: JWT tokens can not be revoked. So, if someone steals your cell phone and that token has no expiration date....bad news.

Comment: @dman actually that's not entirely true... If you create a sort of "hashed" ID on the user that's only used for the `sub` claim in the JWT, if a token gets compromised, just update that hashed ID on the user and the token's `sub` won't match a user with that ID, so it's like it's revoked.